# Uncaught syntax error / uncaught TypeError when using dropcap.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use [dropcap.js](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/dropcap.js) and seem to be getting two errors when I inspect the code:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < world-service.html:71 
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layout' of
>   undefinedworld-service.html:71 (anonymous function)

I think my code is OK -

```js
<script src='../js/dropcap.min.js'></script>
<script>
    var dropcaps = document.querySelectorAll("dropcap"); 
    window.Dropcap.layout(dropcaps, 2);
</script>
```

```html
<p><span class="dropcap">T</span>he BBC’s 28 World Service sites reach over 70 million users world wide every month. As device usage rockets across the world - especially in emerging markets - the imperative to make these sites work on every device became more and more urgent. </p>
```

I'm not sure what is going on. If you want to see the page itself, it lives here: http://ulrikhogrebe.com/projects/world-service.html

Comment: If you inspect the network traffic, is dropcap.min.js actually successfully loaded?

Comment: I was going to suggest this, the code seems fine, it sounds like a problem with the loading of the dropcap js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your dropcap.js code.  The one you're using isn't a .js file, it's HTML.

Make sure you're downloading the zip and grabbing code from there, not just doing a right mouse click > save as on GitHub

Comment: Doh! Yup - just figured that one too. Sorry!